# Derivative with respect to another derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a function $f = 4\pi x^2$, where x is a function of $ln(a)$. The problem  I am running into is that I need to compute
$\frac{\partial}{\frac{\partial x}{\partial ln(a)}}\left(4\pi x^2\right)$.

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial ln(a)}$ is not analytically known, but the goal is to numerically solve coupled 2nd order ODE's. x is one of the variables in the system. How would I approach this? I tried using the chain rule but I always end up with one differential that I cannot do anything with.

Comment: Think about what kind of change of variables could be useful.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that? I'm not seeing the connection between $x^2$ and $ln(a)$ that will give a meaningful change.